# How do I push to stack with unqiue_ptr without making a copy?

Tags: c++, c++11

Originally I made a stack that took a abstract type of `GameState*`. So that'll be...

`std::stack<GameState*> gameStates`

However, someone informed me that if I wanted to retain ownership that I should use C++11's smart pointer `unique_ptr`. So that'll be...

`std::stack<std::unique_ptr<GameState>> gameStates`

Now whenever I push my `GameState` onto the stack, my compiler complains. I'm doing something wrong apparently...

It says..

`no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list`

```
SplashScreen splashScreen1(game); //gameState object declaration
gameStates.push(std::move(&splashScreen1)); //move to stack without copying
```

The red line where the error appears is right under the `.` in `gameStates.push(std::move(&splashScreen1))`

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is designed to own *heap memory*, you're trying to give it *stack memory*.

What you'd like to do is:

```
std::unique_ptr<GameState> splashScreen1Ptr(new GameState(game));
gameStates.push(std::move(splashScreen1Ptr));
```

Comment: I forgot to mention my `GameState` type is abstract, so how do I go about doing this with a abstract type ?

I know abstract types can't be instantiated so is `unique_ptr` useless in my situation ?

Comment: @PrimRock You can pass a derived pointer: `std::unique_ptr<Base> smartPtr(new Derived);` Just make sure you have a virtual destructor!

Comment: Ok, gotcha! One last question ? After I do `std::unique_ptr<GameState> splashScreen1(new SplashScreen(game));` it allocates  the SplashScreen type with new, but as soon as it runs the statement `GameStates.push(std::move(splashScreen1);` the value of splashScreen1 becomes empty, and then I get a error stating that its a `nullptr` when I call the function at runtime. It only works when I reset the pointer back to the SplashScreen object like so `splashScreen1.reset(new SplashScreen(game);` How come I need to use `new` twice ?

Comment: Moving from a `std::unique_ptr` _transfers_ ownership. That means _the moved from object will be empty after the move_ (This is what makes it _unique_). By resetting it to a new pointer, you're effectively creating a completely separate object from the one you pushed onto your vector. If you want to refer to the same object, however, you can keep it's pointer using `splashScreen1Ptr.get()` _before_ the move, or you can access it directly through the vector.

Comment: Ahh....I'll just access it **directly** using the stack's `top()` function like you said, instead of resetting the pointer." Thank you so much! You were a big help! :3